# jQuery insertion between <a> tags

Tags: jquery

Here is one piece of code:

```
<li class="Menu1"><a href="Page1.php"></a>
```

Using jQuery, is there a way to insert some text between the opening and closing tags to equate this:

```
<li class="Menu1"><a href="Page1.php">SOME TEXT</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to insert plain text, use `.text()`:

```
$('.Menu1 a').text('plain text');
```

However, if you want your text to be interpreted as HTML, use `.html()` instead:

```
$('.Menu1 a').html('<span>this will be interpreted as span</span>');
```

If you need to **add** content, instead of **replacing it**, use `prepend()` or `append()`:

```
$('.Menu1 a').append(' (added after)');
$('.Menu1 a').prepend('(added before) ');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L5RMf/)

Comment: Rybak — Thanks. Have you tried it yourself? It yields nothing here. As a relatively newcomer to jQuery, I am intrigued: from reading Bibeault's and Katz' "jQuery in Action" (Greenwich, 2008, pp. 69-70), the instruction $(.Menu1 a).text('plain text') suggests that the links inside the Menu1 class will be REPLACED by the content argument, i.e. 'plain text'. My issue is INSERTING 'plain text' between the > character that ends the opening tag <a of the a element and the < character that starts the closing tag </a. Hope I am stating things clearly enough.

Comment: see my edited answer. I think you should read more about jQuery's API.

Comment: Michal Rybak — Thanks, it works. I had missing quotes to my wrapper.

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't forget to accept the answer that was helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use `$('.Menu1 a').html('SOME TEXT');`

Comment: @Christian Ternus — Thanks. Can you please refer to my reply to Michal Rybak, for it applies to your solution too, I should think? As to the instruction [wrapper].html(text), Bibeault and Katz, op. cit. p. 68, sum up the command syntax this way: "Sets the passed HTML fragment as the content of all matched elements".

Answer (score 1):

The following will insert the same text for every matching `a`:

```
$('.Menu1 a').text('some text');
```

If, however, you have a given array of text with which to populate the `a` elements:

```
var textStrings = ['Some text for link 1', 'Some different text for link 2', 'Yet more...'];
$('ul li a').text(function(i){
    return textString[i];
});
```

References:

- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: — Thanks. Can you please refer to my reply to Michal Rybak, for it applies to your solution too, I should think?

Comment: David Thomas — Solved, thanks. Very useful piece of info about arrayed strings.